# Using sigtrap within a perl module, how do I get the trap received back in the object context?

Tags: perl, module, signals

Have the following in my module's BEGIN section:

```
use sigtrap qw(handler shutdown normal-signals);
use sigtrap qw(die untrapped normal-signals stack-trace any error-signals);
```

But when sigtrap catches INT,etc.. what I get in my shutdown sub only contains the trap and not the object handle.  No $self.

```
sub shutdown {
    my $sig = shift || 'Nothing';   
    print "Got signal: $sig\n";
    exit;
}
```

simply returns

```
Got signal: INT
```

My DESTROY get's called right on time after this and has access to the object handle, but because I didn't have access to the handle in my shutdown, I couldn't store it and have no idea what the signal was.

I need to know what trap I got so my DESTROY method can log what caused the shutdown.

Perhaps sigtrap isn't the best choice here.  Opinions welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked [`sigtrap`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?sigtrap), it's not specifically an OO module, if you want to use it as one, you may need to use a *closure* instead of an object method.

So you might define your class like so:

```
package SigHandler;

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    return bless { @_ }, $class;
}

sub on_signal_int { 
    my $self = shift;
    ...
}

sub get_handler { 
    my $self       = shift;
    my @other_args = shift;
    ...
    return sub { 
        my $sig = shift;
        if ( $sig == INT ) { 
            return $self->on_signal_int();
        }
    };
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
use handler => SigHandler->new->get_handler, 'normal-signals';
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl's signal handlers, including those set with `sigtrap` are program level, and not object level.  So when perl calls the handler, it does not have any object to pass you.

If you want to clean up a bunch of objects when you receive a signal, you will need to code your module to keep track of the objects it has created.  Then when you receive a signal, you can go through those objects and perform any destroy methods.

Something like this should get you started:

```
{package Test;
    use Scalar::Util 'weaken';
    use sigtrap handler => \&cleanup, 'normal-signals';

    my %objects;

    sub new {
        my ($class, $msg) = @_;
        my $self = [$msg];
        bless $self, $class;
        weaken($objects{$self} = $self);  # prevent memory leak
        $self
    }

    sub cleanup {
        my ($sig) = @_;
        say "cleanup on $sig";
        defined and $_->DESTROY for values %objects;
        exit;
    }

    sub DESTROY {
        my ($self) = @_;
        if (@$self) {
            say "DESTROY $self @$self";
            @$self = ();
            delete $objects{$self}
        }
    }

}

{my $obj1 = Test->new('out of scope')}

my $obj2 = Test->new('in scope');

1 while 1;
```

And when run:

```
$ perl so.pl
DESTROY Test=ARRAY(0x899150) out of scope
^Ccleanup on INT
DESTROY Test=ARRAY(0x824810) in scope
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your insights, but I ended up cheating by using global to track it.
All the exports and common stuff removed for brevity

```
Package Blah;
our $SIG_CAUGHT = '';
BEGIN {
    use sigtrap qw(handler shutdown normal-signals);
    use sigtrap qw(die untrapped normal-signals stack-trace any error-signals);
}
sub shutdown {
    $SIG_CAUGHT = shift;
    exit;
}

sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;
    my $message = 'Daemon shutting down';
    $message .= '.  Caught signal: SIG' . $SIG_CAUGHT if ( $SIG_CAUGHT ne '' );
    $message .= ' with error: ' . $! if $!; 
    $self->logger({severity => 5, message => $message});
    $self->{_dbh} = undef;
}
1;
```

Tested.. correctly handles INT,KILL,DIE, propagating errors when fatal.

One nice side effect is triggering INT is now one keystroke.
Had the issue in the past where I repeatedly had to Control-C my programs to get them to go down.

Comment: Make sure you want `$SIG_CAUGHT` public--where any other handler can mess with `$Blah::SIG_CAUGHT`. Otherwise, it should be lexical ( `my` )